# Mod-Rewrite content negotiation for mixed Accept header?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, semantic-web

I am configuring a lightweight content negotiation mechanism using Apaches's Mod-Rewrite. The configuration should deliver several different data representations (for instance, HTML, XML, RDF/XML, and RSS, although I actually have to consider a few more in my application) on a base resource URL depending on the Accept header of the request:

```
# serve html on base url if requested via accept header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml
RewriteRule ^resource/(.*)$ view/html/$1.html [NC,R=303,L]

# serve xml on base url if requested via accept header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xml
RewriteRule ^resource/(.*)$ view/xml/$1.xml [NC,R=303,L]

# serve rdf on base url if requested via accept header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/rdf\+xml
RewriteRule ^resource/(.*)$ view/rdf/$1.rdf [NC,R=303,L]

# serve rss on base url if requested via accept header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/rss\+xml
RewriteRule ^resource/(.*)$ view/rss/$1.rss [NC,R=303,L]

# serve html as default response (keep at bottom)
RewriteRule ^resource/(.*)$ view/html/$1.html [NC,R=303,L]
```

This works pretty fine if the request is sending pure Accept headers, but I run into some trouble when mixed Accept headers are sent. In that case, my configuration does not respect any given q-value in the header, and I end up serving the first matching content type according to the (arbitrary) ordering of my RewriteRules. E.g., I incorrectly serve text/html for the following request:

```
Accept: application/rdf+xml;q=0.5,text/html;q=.3
```

Is there any way how I can make my configuration take the q-values of the Accept header into account? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to use server-side scripting (e.g., PHP, Python, etc.)? I’m looking for a .htaccess solution and haven’t found a solution yet: [Redirect depending on preferred language (Accept-Language) with .htaccess](http://serverfault.com/q/655834/131794)

Comment: @unor: When nothing else is possible, I guess I could use server sided scripting, but in my case this would require a fair amount of tweaking the established infrastructure. I would be way more happy if there were an Apache configuration solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in content negotiation functionality with a [type map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). You may need to tweak your filenames / URLs or use rewrite rules *after* applying the type map.